# jda: if i do get @aRole nothing happens, in very stuck at this part :/

Tags: java, discord, bots, discord-jda

```
package com.zushee.The_Zushee_Server;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Role;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.message.MessageReceivedEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class Welcome2 extends ListenerAdapter {

    public void onMessageReceived(MessageReceivedEvent event) {
        

        Role role = event.getMessage().getMentionedRoles().get(0);

        if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().equals("get" + role)) {
            event.getGuild().addRoleToMember("myusername#6942", role).queue();
        }
    }
}
```

the username and role have no errors so i dont know why it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it's easier to check for the command using the existing if-clause - just slightly modified - and then adding the mentioned role:

```
if (event.getMessage().getContentRaw().split(" ").get(0).equals("get")) {
        event.getGuild().addRoleToMember(event.getMember(), role).queue();
}
```

In the if-clause, we now split the message by spaces to get an array of words. The first word will be the command, in your case "get".